# How to add multiple d3 items to one page

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to add a line graph below a d3 map but the map and line graph show up below where the map is supposed to be and I'm stuck. I've I created seperate div tags with distinct id's. How is this done. Thank you.

Here my gist I'm trying to fix. 
https://bl.ocks.org/centem/81945b90ca4c20da27c54dd89e9acebe

Comment: My first thought is that you're redundantly creating an svg variable for both visualizations.  Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but perhaps there are conflicts due to the asynchronous data calls (i.e., by the time the world map data call finishes, the svg variable actually refers to the second svg).

Comment: Thank you snapjs! I named the second svg svg2 and that worked. Now I have to try to seperate the css styling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to formalize my comment as an answer since it worked for you: My first thought is that you're redundantly creating an svg variable for both visualizations. Normally that wouldn't be an issue, but perhaps there are conflicts due to the asynchronous data calls (i.e., by the time the world map data call finishes, the svg variable actually refers to the second svg).